# How to send push notification directly in indivisual watch app (using watchOS 6 ) without iPhone?

Tags: watchos-6

I am developing independent watch app using watchOS 6 and I want to use push notification in this app. So, Please guide me what is the process of integrate APNS in watch OS 6 without using iPhone.
and registerForRemoteNotifications() method is not working watchOS6.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I get the token, but my server is rejecting and also passing back `DeviceTokenNotForTopic`

Comment: registerForRemoteNotifications is working fine now.

Comment: What did you set your topic as?